# Configure L2TPv3 on Ubuntu using hostnames for peers instead of IP

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, tunnel, l2tp

Is it possible to configure L2TPv3 using ip l2tp commands on Ubuntu 18.04 but using hostnames for peers instead of static IP addresses ?
If so can someone give me a hint on how to do this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using prol2tp.com solutions.